# How to correctly reverse a boolean with the ! operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with Material UI and React for the first time doing an exercise and I cannot enable a button once clicked a second time after it was disabled.

here is the code:

```
const [hello, setHello] = useState(true)
  <Button variant='contained' color='primary' disabled={hello ? false : true} onClick={() => setHello(!hello)}>
    Click Me
  </Button>
```

When the page starts the button is enabled

[image]

and when I click for the first time it becomes disabled as it should

[image]

The problem is that it stays disabled when clicked again.
Shouldn't setHello(!hello) change hello into its opposite boolean value?

Comment: You disabled it by clicking first time, so 2nd click doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to toggle a boolean value in a React state update is to use a functional state update.

```
onClick={() => setHello(hello => !hello)}
```

The button's disabled attribute could also use a little applied Boolean Zen since the `hello` state is already a boolean value there's no need to use a ternary operator ***just*** to assign a boolean value.

```
disabled={!hello}
```

The bigger issue you have though is after disabling the button it's now no longer clickable, so you'll need some *other* means to toggle the `hello` state back in order to re-enable the button.

Comment: Or simply `() => setHello(!hello)` will also do the job.

Comment: @MatthewKwong Sure, until more than 1 `onClick` callback is *somehow* enqueued and the subsequent state updates overwrite the previous ones. See this [Regular vs Functional State Updates Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-regular-and-functional-state-updates-2rtbk) I created and use periodically to demonstrate the issue and why functional state updates are important. The rule of thumb should be that *any* time the next state value *depends* on *any* previous state value, use a functional update.

Comment: @DrewReese I was ignoring the fact that the disabled button is not clickable anymore. Now it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
const [hello, setHello] = useState(true)
<Button variant='contained' color='primary' disabled={!hello} onClick={() => setHello(hello => !hello)}>
    Click Me
</Button>
```

Comment: That's not the issue here, it will change nothing.